# Can we execute IF ELSE without the procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

Please find my code and provide me any alternate way to execute this code without procedure.

````
delimiter $$
create procedure dm()
begin
  IF EXISTS (select * from sainikpuri_purchases  where barcode = 12012271314) THEN
    update sainikpuri_purchases set quantity = quantity+2 where barcode = 12012271314;update purchases set quantity = quantity-2 where barcode = 12012271314;
  ELSE 
    INSERT INTO sainikpuri_purchases(id, vendor_name, quantity, from_location, location, cost, cost_of_price,invoice_number,serial_number,sarees_category,paid_gst,profit_percentage,sales_price,tag,barcode,discount,created_at,updated_at,status) SELECT id, vendor_name, 2, 'KPM', 'SNP', cost, cost_of_price,invoice_number,serial_number,sarees_category,paid_gst,profit_percentage,sales_price,tag,barcode,discount,created_at,updated_at,status FROM purchases where barcode = '12012271314';update sainikpuri_purchases set updated_at = current_timestamp where barcode = '12012271314';update purchases set quantity = quantity-2 where barcode = '12012271314';
  END IF;
end $$
delimiter ; call dm();```
````

Comment: yes- you can use direcly **INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** see:   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: great idea, can i use another table column here? like c=b.quantity+1;

Comment: yes, you can do anything. You anly must have one or more unique Keys. if one key exists the statement will perform the update

Comment: sainikpuri_purchases(id, vendor_name, quantity, from_location, location, cost, cost_of_price,invoice_number,serial_number,sarees_category,paid_gst,profit_percentage,sales_price,tag,barcode,discount,created_at,updated_at,status) SELECT id, vendor_name,2, 'KPM', 'SNP', cost, cost_of_price,invoice_number,serial_number,sarees_category,paid_gst,profit_percentage,sales_price,tag,barcode,discount,created_at,updated_at,status FROM purchases where barcode = '12012271314' on duplicate key update sainikpuri_purchases.quantity = quantity+2;
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'quantity' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: can you post the query

Comment: I found this and used the table name with column and works now. Thanks a lot